# MVC download of clickonce Setup.exe and display confirmation view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, clickonce

I'll start by saying i'm a C# MVC newbie, but I've set up a site with Identity Management and extended the database with some custom tables to store additional info about my users, so I'm not a total neophyte. I've been working on a VB WPF application that I want to deploy from my new website and that is where I'm running into an issue.

I've created a new controller (User) and a couple of views (Download) & (Setup). I created a downloadmodel used by the download view.

In abstract what I am doing is displaying the download view (get) which has three checkboxes to confirm the user has read the Overview, Installation, and Terms of Service. These are boolean values in the model. I also have a string response message in the model, that displays just above the submit button. Here is the model:

```
public class DownloadModel
{
    public bool Overview { get; set; }
    public bool Installation { get; set; }
    public bool TermsOfService { get; set; }
    public string Response { get; set; }

    public DownloadModel()
    {
        Overview = false;
        Installation = false;
        TermsOfService = false;
        Response = "After checking boxes click the button to begin installation";
    }

}
```

My User Controller handles the Get to initially display the download view, and then in the Post it checks to see if all the checkboxes were ticked, if not it updates the response message and returns the view. 
If the checkboxes are all checked then it pulls the subscriber (which must exist because it was created when the user verified their e-mail via the account controller - identity management), then proceeds to update the subscriber with the original (if new) or last download date(s). At this point I want to begin downloading the clickonce setup.exe file, before returning the setup view.

```
[Authorize]
public class UserController : Controller
{
    // GET: User/Download
    public ActionResult Download()
    {
        return View(new DownloadModel { });
    }

    // Post: User/Download
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Download(DownloadModel downloadcheck)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(downloadcheck);
        }

        //check to see if all the boxes were checked
        if (downloadcheck.Overview == true &
                        downloadcheck.Installation == true &
                        downloadcheck.TermsOfService == true)
        {
            //yes - so let's proceed 
            //first step is to get the subscriber
            Subscriber tSubscriber = new Subscriber();
            tSubscriber.Email = User.Identity.Name;
            bool okLoad = tSubscriber.LoadByEmail();
            if (okLoad == false)
            {
                //we have a real problem. a user has logged in but they are not yet
                //a valid subscriber?
                throw new Exception("Subscriber not found");

            }

            // update subscriber with download in process...
            if (tSubscriber.OriginalDownload == DateTime.MinValue)
            {
                tSubscriber.OriginalDownload = DateTime.Now;
                tSubscriber.LastDownload = tSubscriber.OriginalDownload;
            }
            else
            {
                tSubscriber.LastDownload = DateTime.Now;
            }
            if (tSubscriber.UpdateDownloaded() == false)
            {
                //update of download dates failed
                //another problem that shouldnt occur.
                downloadcheck.Response = "A problem occured downloading your setup."
                    + "Try again. If this error continues please contact support.";
                return View(downloadcheck);
            }

            //download dates have been updated for the subscriber so let's start the download!

            //THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO BEGIN THE DOWNLOAD

            return View("Setup");
        }
        else
        {
            // all boxes were not checked - update message
            downloadcheck.Response = "Please confirm you have reviewed the above information " 
                + "by checking all of the boxes before clicking on the button.";
            return View(downloadcheck);
                        }

    }


}
```

The download view is pretty straight forward, and the setup view simply confirms the download was started and provides a link to the help-setup page.

I'm really a bit lost here. I thought I'd plug in a return new filepathresponse, but I can't do that and return the setup view.

My other thought was to somehow trigger the download of my /xxx/setup.exe from within the setup view as it is returned - but I'm at a loss as to how to accomplish this.

I'll be the first to admit that my mvc c# code is probably overly verbose and my approach to how I've done this may be totally wrong, but I'm just scrambling to get this done so I can deploy my WPF app to select Beta users for testing. It's been a long time living off savings and I can smell go-live from here.

One final note, I'm using setup.exe clickonce deployment of my wpf app for simplicity, as there are .net and localsqldb prerequisites, but I will not be using automated updates - not that this is really relevant.

Appreciate all input and advice.

Answer (score 0):

After more digging and hacking I've found a solution that works. Firstly in my setup view (confirmation page) I added a simple script to initiate a new function in my user controller:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location.href = "/user/sendfile/"
</script>
```

The controller change was simple too. For testing I just used a txt file.

```
//  User/SendFile
    public ActionResult SendFile()
    {
        string path = @"~/xxxx/anyfile.txt";
        string content = "application/txt";
        //string content = "application/x-ms-application";
        return new FilePathResult(path, content)
        {
            FileDownloadName = "mynewtext.txt"
        };
    }
```

What is really interesting about this solution is that the FileDownloadName is what the file content is downloaded as. So in this way I can refer to the actual setup.exe file in the path, but then name the downloaded exe anything I want. Bonus :)

Comment: This worked as shown for a test text file, but when I switched to the setup.exe file from the clickonce deployment of a WPF app, I ran into further issues. It downloaded and ran, installed the prerequisite, but then couldn't find the xxx.application file. I'll continue working next week on this and post an update as soon as I have an answer.

Comment: OK - I've resolved this. Make sure 1) that the Publish / Installation Folder is set to the correct http(s)://xxxx folder where your application was uploaded, and 2) that the Publish / Updates / Update Location folder is also set to the same folder (even if you are not using automatic updates). The Setup.exe will find the xxx.application folder and you will be good to go.